# TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

i was working on a discord bot using discord.js but i had this problem that i dont know how to fix
i made a command that tests if the bot is online or not here is the code for it
just before i show any code i want to say that im a bit new at javascript so this problem confused me a lot

```
module.exports = {
    name : "onstatus",
    description : "",
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send("online");
    }
}
```

so when i type !-onstatus
what i expected to happen was the bot responding. but it doesnt and it shows this error in vs code

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
```

i had another command that works but for some reason this doesnt here is the code for the one that works

```
module.exports = {
    name : 'ping',
    description : '',
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong');
        
    }
}
```

when i run this one and type !-ping it works

if you want the code for the whole bot here you go

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "!-";

const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('leobot is currently online ');
});

client.on('message' , message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command == 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'developerofleobot'){
        client.commands.get('developerofleobot').execute(message.args);
    } else if (command == 'onstatus'){
        client.commands.get('onstatus').execute(message.args);
    }
});


client.login('######');
```

Comment: client.commands.get('developerofleobot').execute(message.args); i think you shoud put ```,``` in between execute(message.args)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code

```
client.commands.get('onstatus').execute(message.args);
```

**comma** would be next after message not dot

```
client.commands.get('onstatus').execute(message,args);
```

Comment: If it work, accept the answer so that others who have the same problem can know!